# IOS runs my Unity Project at low framerate

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

I've got simple 2D Unity project which works fine on Android. However when I build my game on Virtual Machine for iOS, game starts running at low framerate compared to Android. This happens me on all my Unity projects. What might be the problem?

Comment: Have you looked at the information shown in the profiler?  it is quite impossible for us, who do not know your application or your code, to figure out what might be the issue. The profiler will give you information about what part of your code takes longest to process https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html

Comment: You should test your app on a real iOS device before jumping to conclusions. What Virtual Machine for iOS are you running it on?